# Batch file to switch between browser tabs

Tags: windows, batch-file, browser, scheduled-tasks, monitoring

I have two browser tabs running monitoring applications on a screen. I want to automate switching between tabs after lets say every 2 mins. I think this can be achieved by creating a scheduled task in windows which execute a batch file every 2 mins. Batch file will switch the tab. I need help creating such batch file. Thanks.

Comment: That would very much depend on whether the *browser* has an exposed API for switching tabs - and that would depend on which browser you're using. Should we assume IE, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use VBScript to do that,

Example for IE :

Create a file Switch.vbs with this :

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
Wscript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "^{TAB}"
Wscript.Sleep 1500
```

After opening your 2 tabs in IE run the command every 2 minutes :

```
wscript.exe switch.vbs
```