# SendKey to specific application

Tags: windows, batch-file, browser, scheduled-tasks, monitoring

My requirement is to automatically toggle the Internet Explorer multiple tabs. After looking over web and stackoverflow I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651893/batch-file-to-switch-between-browser-tabs) to come with a solution .vbs file as -

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
while 1
    WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
    WScript.Sleep 7000
    WshShell.SendKeys("^{TAB}")
wend
```

But the issue with this approach is it sends the keys to all the active applications.
I need it to trigger the keys to only Internet Explorer.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem.
I am able to achieve this using C# script -

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SendKeyAppDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr ptr);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore").FirstOrDefault();
            if (p.ProcessName == "iexplore")
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
                    SetForegroundWindow(h);
                    SendKeys.SendWait("^{TAB}");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```